# how to iterate over col in 2D vector c++?

Tags: c++

I have the following vector of vector containning tree string elements, I want to know how to iterate over col element instead of normal loop over rows

```
vector<vector<string>> vec2Dstr =
{
    { "A2", "A4", "A6" },
    { "B2", "B4", "B6" },
    { "C2", "C4", "C6" },
    { "D2", "D4", "D6" },
    { "E2", "E4", "E6" }
};
```

the output expected is :

```
A2 B2 C2 D2 E2
A4 B4 C4 D4 E4
A6 B6 C6 D6 E6
```

code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector<vector<string>> vec2Dstr  =
    {
        { "A2", "A4", "A6" },
        { "B2", "B4", "B6" },
        { "C2", "C4", "C6" },
        { "D2", "D4", "D6" },
        { "E2", "E4", "E6" }
    };
        for(auto & j : vec2Dstr ) {
            for(int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++ )
                cout << " => " <<j.at(i) << endl;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you try? Does it work on paper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this following code might do the aim expected!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector<vector<string>> vec2Dstr  =
    {
        { "A2", "A4", "A6" },
        { "B2", "B4", "B6" },
        { "C2", "C4", "C6" },
        { "D2", "D4", "D6" },
        { "E2", "E4", "E6" }
    };

    size_t total_col = vec2Dstr[0].size();
    for (int col=0; col<total_col; ++col)
    {
        for(auto& row : vec2Dstr)
        {
            cout << row[col] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much Sir, I appreciate your help, you are the only person who give the right answer , unfortunately people instead of giving the help they critic us

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loops are wrong. How do you expect it to show `5` elements when you hardcode a limit of `3`. Rewrite the `for` loop using this logic:

1. Iterate `vec2Dstr` from `0` to `length`.
2. Display `vec2Dstr[i][j]` where `j` increases after each loop we described above.

If you still are stuck after this let me know. Show me some code first.